# padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) is not working

Tags: ios, css, angular, webkit

I am writing a web app in Angular 8 and I want to implement full screen mode on an iPad.

To index.html I have added:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

and

```
viewport-fit=cover
```

In the CSS file of my outmost component I have:

```
padding: env(safe-area-inset-top) env(safe-area-inset-right) env(safe-area-inset-bottom) env(safe-area-inset-left);
```

If I place a shortcut on the desktop on my iPad pro (newest generation) and use that to open the app in fullscreen mode everything works nicely. The padding is keeping the app within safe areas.

[image]

I would however like to make it easier for user to switch to fullscreen mode, so I have implemented this example: https://bubblin.io/blog/fullscreen-api-ipad

```
toggleFullScreen() {
        if (document.fullscreenElement || document['mozFullScreenElement'] || document['webkitFullscreenElement']) {
            if (document['cancelFullScreen']) {
                document['cancelFullScreen']();
            } else {
                if (document['mozCancelFullScreen']) {
                    document['mozCancelFullScreen']();
                } else {
                    if (document['webkitCancelFullScreen']) {
                        document['webkitCancelFullScreen']();
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            const _element = document.documentElement;
            if (_element.requestFullscreen) {
                _element.requestFullscreen();
            } else {
                if (_element['mozRequestFullScreen']) {
                    _element['mozRequestFullScreen']();
                } else {
                    if (_element['webkitRequestFullscreen']) {
                        _element['webkitRequestFullscreen'](Element['ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT']);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It switches the app to fullscreen mode, but it doesn't respect env(safe-area-inset-top) so the top of the app is in from of the date, battery left, etc.

[image]

The env(safe-area-inset-bottom) is working correctly.

So how can i make env(safe-area-inset-top) work correctly when I use the javascript function toggleFullScreen() to go to fullscreen?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `env(safe-area-inset-top)`, which, combined with the other three "safe areas", is designed for iOS devices, try:

```css
    header {
      position: fixed;
      left: env(titlebar-area-x);
      top: env(titlebar-area-y);
      width: env(titlebar-area-width);
      height: env(titlebar-area-height);
    }
    
    main {
      margin-top: env(titlebar-area-height);
    }
```

And write a javascript function to see if the user is on a  iOS device; if so, the standard (what you're using) CSS is used. If not, the CSS from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/env) is used.